# Can't run uwsgi .ini file with systemd emperor

Tags: django, uwsgi, systemd

I am trying to set up uwsgi.service to run on systemd for Django 1.10 on Linode with Fedora 24.

/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ofey/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This should then call,
/etc/uwsgi/emporer.ini

```
[uwsgi]
emperor = /etc/uwsgi/vassals
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
limit-as = 1024
logto = /tmp/uwsgi.log
```

I then use a symbolic link,

```
$ sudo ln -s /home/ofey/djangoForum/django.ini /etc/uwsgi/vassals/
```

to 
/home/ofey/djangoForum/django.ini

```
[uwsgi]
project = djangoForum
base = /home/ofey

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/djangoenv
module = crudProject.wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 2

socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

I have restarted all with,

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx.service
$ sudo systemctl retart uwsgi.service
```

The last command gives,

```
Job for uwsgi.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status uwsgi.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

$ sudo systemctl status uwsgi.service
```

gives,

```
● uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Dec 07 23:56:28 ofeyspi systemd[1]: Starting uWSGI Emperor...
Dec 07 23:56:28 ofeyspi uwsgi[7834]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
Dec 07 23:56:28 ofeyspi systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 07 23:56:28 ofeyspi systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI Emperor.
Dec 07 23:56:28 ofeyspi systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 07 23:56:28 ofeyspi systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 07 23:56:28 ofeyspi systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 07 23:56:28 ofeyspi systemd[1]: Stopped uWSGI Emperor.
Dec 07 23:56:28 ofeyspi systemd[1]: uwsgi.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 07 23:56:28 ofeyspi systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI Emperor.
```

I can not figure out why uwsgi.service will not run.

uwsgi runs when I don't go through systemd and instead use,

$ sudo --ini django.ini

Comment: If you `stat` the folder that the project is in, who owns it?  Is it www-data, root, or another user?  That it works when you run it with sudo makes me wonder if it's permissions-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for that is that Emperor is not able to:

1. create the .pid file to write the processID;
2. create the unix-socket files for the vassals (seems to be not your case, since you are using :3031 port);
3. write to the log file specified by `--logto` option (*/tmp/uwsgi.log* in your case).

This often happens when any of these files exist and are owned by another user (most likely, root) or are located in a directory to which the user starting the service is not able to write.

Systemd's status log is not very informative on this subject. So, the quickest way to identify the case is to run your `ExecStart` command from systemd's service **not as root** and to see the output:

```
$ /home/ofey/djangoenv/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
```

If the output shows that the problem is permission, try the following.

Since you are going to run your server on behalf of `www-data` user, as it has been suggested already, make sure you have:

```
[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
```

in your systemd unit config. Then, make sure the .pid files and unix-socket files (if any) are created under that directory (i.e. under /run/uwsgi) by adding this to your vassals .ini files:

```
runtime_dir = /run/uwsgi
pidfile=%(runtime_dir)/%n.pid

# if you prefer using unix-socket instead of a port
socket = %(runtime_dir)/%n.sock

# trying to chmod-socket is useless with a port, by the way
chmod-socket    = 664
```

The `%n` variable in the given example stands for the vassal's .ini file name without extension (see the [full-list here](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html#magic-variables)).

Finally, make sure the `--logto` file specified in Emperor's and vassals' configs is writable by such.

Please note, if you run `uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini` as **root** and then terminate the procecc with ctrl+D, it will leave the above-mentioned temp files existing and **owned by root**, which will prevent other owners (like *www-data*) from writing to them, until you delete the files or `chown/chmod` them again.

Answer (score 1):

The [uwsgi systemd docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html) advise adding `RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi` to your service file. Try adding that.

Also check `/tmp/uwsgi.log` to see if any logging was generated there.

Comment: I've added that, thanks. But what about ExecStart=/root/uwsgi/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
 Should that refer to the uwsgi file in the virtualenv or on the system? So should it be /usr/local/share/applications/test_project/bin which is the virtualenv or the uwsgi binary on my system at /usr/bin/uwsgi ? I've reinstalled Django inside the new virtualenv at /usr/local/share/applications/test_project/

Comment: Also in the uwsgi systemd docs you pointed to it says "Be careful with some systemd versions (e.g. 215 in Debian Jessie), since SIGQUIT signal will trash the systemd services. Use KillSignal=SIGTERM + “die-on-term” UWSGI option there." I wonder could this be an issue also?

Answer (score 1):

Comment out `KillSignal = SIGQUIT`

It can cause problems, see http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html

also causes issues on Centos 7